# Is it possible from javascript/browser to prevent OS X from sleeping?

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, firefox, safari

Is it possible from javascript in the browser to prevent OS X from sleeping?

I'm writing a library for uploading large files, and we're finding that the default power settings in Mountain Lion (sleep after 15 minutes, when plugged in) are causing issues. The uploads are paused while the OS sleeps. They resume upon wake, but its making the uploads much slower for anyone who leaves their Mac to sit.

If there is no official API for this, are there any hacks? Play a silent 1px x 1px video on loop?

thanks

tom

Comment: I do not think JavaScript (and even less while executed in a web browser) has that kind of `power`.
Actually, I would be quite scared if anybody could control anybody's else computer through a website using JS.

Comment: Yes, `alert('Please adjust your sleep settings so your Mac won't sleep until the download finishes. Regards, developer')`. :-)

Answer (score 3):

One approach that works is to play a video in the background. You can adapt this project's `sleep.js` file to suit your needs:

https://github.com/ivanmaeder/computer-sleep

Tested with Chrome.

Comment: I tested it with Chrome. It worked when I stayed on the tab. It didn't went idle for several hours..